# Functionality is not working when app is terminated and when it is live also

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

As we all know when app is terminated nothing works in iOS but some how by following code(written inside applicationWillTerminate) I manage to did that but when app is on test flight or it is live, nothing is working after app termination.

for _ in 1...28{
            updateCounter()
            sleep(30)
//update counter update my firebase data
        }

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what are you trying to do actually? Please elaborate

'func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) ' is called when application is about to terminate. You can save data if appropriate

You can also see for 'applicationDidEnterBackground' if you want to perform something while app is in background.

Comment: @Waqas, my code is working fine when I enter in background, even apple says you can't do anything after is terminated (i.e by pressing home button twice and swiping up) but it is working fine because thread is holding my data by Thread.sleep method, However when I make my application live or put it in play store, this same functionality is not working.

Comment: As simple I want to preform something when app is killed which is not possible but I have seen it getting done.

Comment: (i.e by pressing home button twice and swiping up) you want to perform something before app gets killed. or its already killed and at some point you want to perform something ?

Comment: And `but it is working fine because thread is holding my data by Thread.sleep method` Thats not a good practice. One thing you can do is run your application in 'Release Mode' and then check where it differs.

Comment: Thank you Waqas your help is meaningful for me. I will try to do as you suggested, but this Thread maybe a private entity, there can be a chance that apple is neglecting this functionality?

Comment: I have seen same issue many time here on Stack overflow, many people wants to do the same, they have been doing is by VoIP Push, silent push, amazon SNS etc, but somehow manage to do like this, if this approach won't work, is there any other way to achive updation on app even when app is terminated?

Comment: Only the `Silent push` can help you in that case.